# PayPal Adaptive Payments API - Delayed Chain Payments (PHP, JavaScript)

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

On my server-side, I just started receiving positive responses from the Adaptive Payment API through the AngelEye PHP SDK to achieve delayed chained payments, which hold funds by a primary receiver for up to 90 days dispersed to secondary receiver(s) accounts.

On the client-side, I redirect the user to checkout with the RedirectURL returned by my JSON-encoded API response. So the worst is over, but I don't understand what PayPal means by *'explicitly executing a payment to secondary receivers'*?

Does **explicit** imply that I have to login to my PayPal and disburse the funds to the secondary receiver account(s) manually after they *meet my criteria* that I have setup? Primarily, I'm trying to figure out how to **delay the chain** in a delay chained payment. Can I just have the funds automatically sent somehow on my server once I, the application-owner, receives *criteria* from secondary receiver(s) such as a tracking number

**Delayed Chained Payments**

```
By default, payments to all receivers in a chained payment are immediate. 
However, you can choose to delay a payment to a secondary receiver. For 
example, as primary receiver, you may require secondary receivers to perform 
some action, such as shipping goods or waiting for expiration of a return 
period, before making payment. To complete the payment, you must explicitly 
execute a payment to secondary receivers after the sender pays you. The 
payment must occur within 90 days, after which you cannot complete the payment 
as part of the original chained payment.
```

Comment: Hi! You should post your solution as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
Step 4: Make a Payment to One or More Secondary Receivers

When the time comes to pay secondary receivers, call ExecutePayment, 
specifying the pay key from Step 1. For more information on this call, see 
the ExecutePayment API Operation.

When the time comes to pay secondary receivers, all secondary receivers must 
be paid at once.
```

**PayKey** + **ExecutePayment** = ANSWER!